# Excepting a top level declaration after Kotlin upgrade

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

After Kotlin upgrade, I started gettting the following error:

> Excepting a top level declaration.

What I need to implement is an Entity with a Foreing Key. This is my implementation:

```
@Entity(
    tableName="dogs",
    foreignKeys=@ForeignKey(
            entity=Owner.class, parentColumns="id",
            childColumns="ownerId",
            onDelete=CASCADE),
            indices=@Index(value="ownerId"))
 @TypeConverters(AnimalTypeConverters::class)
 class Dog(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @field:SerializedName("id")
    @field:Expose
    var id: Int,
    @field:SerializedName(value = "ownerId")
    var ownerId: Int,
    @field:SerializedName(value = "name")
    var name: String)
```

But after

```
Dog.class,
```

The message "Excepting a top level declaration." appears.

Before the upgrade, everything worked.

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to put the `[ ]` around some array that you pass as a single variable

Comment: yes! That is what I've just wrote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! There is no much information about it.

This is the modification:

```
@Entity(
    tableName="dogs",
    foreignKeys=[
        (ForeignKey(
                entity=Owner::class, 
                parentColumns=["id"],
                childColumns=["ownerId"],
                onDelete=CASCADE
                )
        )]
)
```

The most important thing is to use

```
[]
```

So you can manage severals foreing key.

Thanks and good coding!